# How to get value of XML Element Attribute from xml file in php with DOMXPath

Tags: php, xml, xpath

here is simple XML File and i need to get the value of `unitCode` and i am using `DOMXPath` object to get the values.

```
<cbc:ConsumerUnitQuantity unitCode="BX">
    80.000
</cbc:ConsumerUnitQuantity>
```

i have tried

```
$unitCode = $xpath->query('//cbc:ConsumerUnitQuantity [@unitCode=""]')->item(0);
```

Comment: Can you paste a more complete XML example with the `cbc` namespace definition?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the namespace. You XML elements have a namespace prefix, but you did not register one on the Xpath object. Check you document for a `xmlns:cbc` attribute.

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<cbc:ConsumerUnitQuantity xmlns:cbc="your-namespace" unitCode="BX">
    80.000
</cbc:ConsumerUnitQuantity>
XML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml($xml);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$xpath->registerNamespace('ns-cbc', 'your-namespace');

var_dump(
  $xpath->evaluate('string(//ns-cbc:ConsumerUnitQuantity)', NULL, FALSE)
);
```

Unlike `DOMXpath::query()`, `DOMXpath::evaluate()` can return scalar values directly.